# Daily record log to different spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I would like to be able to log the last value with yesterdays timestamp to a completely different Google sheet, but am a bit stomped by the complexity of this.

I have a sheet that logs "daily_gains" (column U) values at random intervals. The time/date (column B) and daily gains column look something like this;

```
    
|date/time (B)      |daily_gains (U) |
|:------------------|---------------:|
|12 Aug 2021, 06:16 |                |
|12 Aug 2021, 06:05 |                |
|12 Aug 2021, 05:55 |                |
|12 Aug 2021, 05:50 |                |
|12 Aug 2021, 04:30 |          2.225 |
|12 Aug 2021, 04:25 |                |
|12 Aug 2021, 04:15 |                |
|12 Aug 2021, 04:05 |                |
|12 Aug 2021, 04:00 |                |
|12 Aug 2021, 03:55 |                |
|12 Aug 2021, 03:20 |         -1.129 |
|12 Aug 2021, 03:10 |                |
|12 Aug 2021, 03:00 |                |
|12 Aug 2021, 02:35 |                |
|12 Aug 2021, 02:30 |                |
|12 Aug 2021, 02:25 |                |
|11 Aug 2021, 20:30 |         -3.306 |
|11 Aug 2021, 20:25 |                |
|11 Aug 2021, 20:10 |                |
|11 Aug 2021, 19:30 |                |
|11 Aug 2021, 18:40 |                |
|11 Aug 2021, 18:30 |                |
|11 Aug 2021, 15:45 |         -2.819 |
|11 Aug 2021, 15:41 |                |
```

What I am trying to do is: Everyday, sometime after midnight, I would like to copy the last `daily_gains` value from the previous day to a different spreadsheet.

In this case, on 12 Aug 2021, 00:10, I would like to copy the value `-3.306` to a new spreadsheet.

I have found this thread: [Daily calculation and record insertion in Google Spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29236/daily-calculation-and-record-insertion-in-google-spreadsheet) which helps some explaining how to use apps script, but it copies from a specific cell to a new sheet in the same document. And my coding knowledge doesn't quite let me extrapolate my specific use case from that.

edit: This spreadsheet shows the data I have and what I am trying to achieve: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fglFHDZOxOfiipMjB9sXWpdzCdgvhZ_PYIrdfPpfL98/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear why you would need to use a script for this, as the report you are asking for can more easily be created with a plain vanilla spreadsheet formula, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      sequence( 
        max(RawData!C2:C) - min(RawData!C2:C), 
        1, 
        min(RawData!C2:C) 
      ), 
      filter( 
        { RawData!C2:C, RawData!G2:G }, 
        RawData!C2:C < today(), 
        not(isblank(RawData!G2:G)) 
      ), 
      { 1, 2 }, 
      false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

See the new '[Solution - arrayformula](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fglFHDZOxOfiipMjB9sXWpdzCdgvhZ_PYIrdfPpfL98/edit#gid=412165011)' sheet in your sample spreadsheet. The first column is formatted as **Format > Number > Date**.

If you absolutely need to use a script for some reason, you can **Insert > New sheet**, name the new sheet `Gains yesterday` and use this formula in cell `A2`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      today() - 1, 
      filter( 
        { RawData!C2:C, RawData!G2:G }, 
        RawData!C2:C < today(), 
        not(isblank(RawData!G2:G)) 
      ), 
      { 1, 2 }, 
      false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

Then use the [appendValuesToArchiveSheet](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/27095918?msgid=27163801) script with these parameters:

```
// [START modifiable parameters]
var rangeToLog = 'Gains yesterday!A2:B2';
var sheetToLogTo = 'Archive';
// [END modifiable parameters]
```

The script will write the values to an 'Archive' sheet in the same spreadsheet file. To automatically copy the log to another spreadsheet, use `importrange()`, or insert a new line right before the `var logSheet` like like this:

```
  // ...
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('...ID...');
  var logSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetToLogTo);
  // ...
```

Replace the `...ID...` bit with the spreadsheet ID of the target spreadsheet. You can get it from the browser address bar when you have the spreadsheet open. It is the part between `/d/` and `/edit`.

Some of the best resources for learning Google Apps Script include the [Beginner's Guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-beginner-guide/), the [New Apps Script Editor guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-ide/), the [Fundamentals of Apps Script with Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1) codelab, the [Extending Google Sheets page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/), [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Comment: the last `daily_gains` entry of a particular day wont be in the same cell every day. the columns are updated in irregular intervals and it wont be possible to predict how many  "empty" entries there are from the last `daily_gains` value to midnight. And also how many entries it already generated after midnight until the script runs. Your script is great though, but is there a way to pinpoint the last entry with a value before midnight?

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Comment: Of course - could have thought of that. I have added a link to an example spreadsheet in the question

Comment: Edited the answer to add an easier solution.

Comment: wow. Still going through your formula - a lot in there I haven't seen before. But it does exactly what I need it to do. thank you